# Stanford Core NLP how to get the probability & margin of error

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

When using the parser or for the matter any of the Annotation in Core NLP, is there a way to access the probability or the margin of error?

To put my question into context, I am trying to understand if there is a way programmatically to detect a case of ambiguity. For instance in the sentence below the verb *desire* is detected as a noun. I would like to be able to know so kind of measure I can access or calculate from the Core NLP APi to tell me there could be an ambiguity.

```
(NP (NP (NNP Whereas)) (, ,) (NP (NNP users) (NN desire) (S (VP (TO to) (VP (VB sell))))))
```