# spacy recognizing "simmer" as a PROPN (basically a noun)

Tags: python

spacy recognizing "simmer" as a PROPN (basically a noun).

I want to read recipes instructions and deconstruct the components, but sometimes spacy or chatGPT vary in recognizing certain words depending on context and word placement in the sentence. Is there any way I can identify correctly a word, like comparing to other database of spacy itself? I tried the en_core_web_lg and en_core_web_trf models. Thanks in advance

Comment: That's probably because "simmer" can be used as both a verb and a noun

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Obtain multiple taggings with Stanford POS Tagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791716/obtain-multiple-taggings-with-stanford-pos-tagger)